# Makefile Issues with C++ & Gtkmm

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make, gtkmm

I am familiar with Gtkmm and C++, but new to Makefiles and am having issues getting mine to actually produce an executable. I know a full Makefile is overkill for the current simplicity of my project, but I am trying to put together a basic template for use in larger projects. I am on Ubuntu 17.10 and running the `make` command from my "build" folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Terminal Output**

```
pearscol@UBUNTU-1710:~/projects/testprogram/build$ make
g++ -o testprogram  `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0`
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In 
function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'testprogram' failed
make: *** [testprogram] Error 1
```

**Source File Structure**

```
 - /build
    - /build/Makefile
 - /src
    - /src/main.cpp
```

**/build/Makefile**

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` -std=c++14 -g -Wall
INCLUDES = -I../include
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
PROGRAM = testprogram
DEPDIR = ../src/
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0`

all: $(PROGRAM)

-include $(OBJS:%.o=$(DEPDIR)/%.Po)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $*.Tpo -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

**/src/main.cpp**

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
      Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "testprogram");
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(400, 200);
    window.set_title("Tutorial");
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the source files using a `$(wildcard ...)` function,
then replace:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

with:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
```

because `src` is where the `*.cpp` files are, with respect to the build directory.

To place the object files in the build directory, then replace:

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

with:

```
$(notdir $(SRCS:.cpp=.o))
```

Finally do one of the following:

Either replace the pattern rule:

```
%.o: %.cpp
```

with:

```
%.o: src/%.cpp
```

Or, leave the pattern rule as it is and add:

```
VPATH := src
```

to the variable settings at the top of your makefile. See
[VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html).

**Asides**

You default target `all` is a [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) target: you are never going to make
a file called `all`, and you assume no such file will ever exist. Better specify it as a `.PHONY` target.

For [defining variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), use simple expansion - `VAR := val` - rather than
recursive expansion - `VAR = val` - unless recursive expansion is needed, which it isn't in your makefile.

Your makefile lacks a [`clean`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) target for
deleting all make-prodicts and restoring the build directory to its pristine
state. It is standard to provide this phony target.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but thank you for providing some insight into how makefiles handle wildcards and paths. The key that I was missing was the `notdir` tag and correct use of `vpath` to specify `src` for the pattern rule to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell,

```
$(CXX) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

results in

```
g++ -o testprogram  `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

because `$(OBJS)` is empty, because `$(SRCS)` is empty, because `*.cpp` matches no files, because your `build` directory contains no `.cpp` files.

Comment: My goal is for it to use the .cpp files from /src/, but then dump the .o and other files in build so that they don't mix in with the source code. I could just remove the build folder altogether and put the Makefile in src, but then it would get messy as full classes are added. Do you know how I could edit my Makefile to do this? I'm using the DEPDIR variable to reference src, but I'm not fluent enough in the make syntax to figure out where it might be missing.

Comment: @ColePearson Why not write your makefile without variables first? Make it work first, then worry about abstracting things out.

Comment: I was able to remove the vars successfully and run it to just compile main.cpp before, but right now my focus is on making it semi-universal to be applied to gtkmm software without needing to look through the source to find all the necessary values. Unless I'm missing something, I think I've found the source of my issue to be needing to add '../src/' to the beginning of the values in SRCS as they are copied with the .cpp to .o change into OBJS. That would be to make it work while putting the .o files into src, but preventing that was my initial goal.